# Me actualiza mi usuario como root

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda , tengo un formulario en donde actualizo los campos de los usuarios el problema es cuando quiero actualizar el nombre de usuario me lo actualiza como root independiente de lo que escriba siempre me lo actualiza como root.

```
<form action="ejecutareditar.php" method="POST" role="form">
<legend>Editar Usuarios</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id">Fecha registro</label>
                                <input type="text" name="fecha_registro" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $fecha_registro ?>" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id">ID</label>
                                <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="email"  value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                                <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" id="usuario"  value="<?php echo $usuario ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required id="email"  value="<?php echo $email ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" required id="password"  value="<?php echo $password ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="privilegio">Perfil</label>
                                <SELECT name="privilegio" size ="1" id="privilegio" style="width:310px " value="<?php echo $privilegio?>">
                              <option >----Seleccione Perfil----</option>
                             <option value="1">Administrador</option>
                             <option value="2">Usuario</option>"

                            </div></SELECT></div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
                            <a href="usuarios.php" title='Editar datos' class='btn btn-danger'>Volver</a>
```

Codigo que actualiza

```
         extract($_POST);
          $server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");

       $sentencia ="UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = '$nombre ', usuario = '$usuario', email = '$email', password = '$password', fecha_registro = '$fecha_registro' ,privilegio='$privilegio' WHERE usuarios. id = $id";

$resent=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
if ($resent==null) {
    echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';

header("location: usuarios.php");

    echo "<script>location.href='usuarios.php'</script>";
}else {


    echo "<script>location.href='usuarios.php'</script>";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$usuario = "root"`

Comment: Si la página que haces está en producción, te recomiendo que apliques la función `password_hash()` a la contraseña antes de almacenarla, es mejor para evitar problemas de seguridad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu sentencia SQL está tomando el valor de la variable `$usuario` que tienes definida para hacer la conexión a tu base de datos.

```
$server = "localhost";
          $usuario = "root";  <-- Esta linea.
         $contraseña = ""; <-- Esta linea también estaría dando problemas.
         $bd = "bdpagina";
```

Te recomiendo cambiar el nombre de las variables que usas para construir tu sentencia SQL para evitar ese problema. Puedes usar los nombres que quieras, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$sentencia ="UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = '$nombre_db ', usuario = '$usuario_db', email = '$email_db', password = '$password_db', fecha_registro = '$fecha_registro_db' ,privilegio='$privilegio_db' WHERE usuarios. id = $id_db";
```

> Es muy importante evitar usar nombres de variables que ya estén en uso para evitar sobrescribir sus valores o obtener resultado inesperados.

Para obtener los valores de tu `form` puedes usar:

```
$nombre_db = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
$email_db = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
$password_db = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['password']);
$privilegio_db = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
```

También te recomiendo revisar los atributos de los `input` de tu formulario porque me parece que algunos atributos tienen valores erróneos.

Comment: Gracias  eso era :)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas sobreescribiendo la variable $usuario.  La solucion es hacer la conexion y despues extaer el contenido de POST asi:

```
          $server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");

       extract($_POST);

       $sentencia ="UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = '$nombre ', usuario = '$usuario', email = '$email', password = '$password', fecha_registro = '$fecha_registro' ,privilegio='$privilegio' WHERE usuarios. id = $id";

$resent=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
if ($resent==null) {
    echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';

header("location: usuarios.php");

    echo "<script>location.href='usuarios.php'</script>";
}else {


    echo "<script>location.href='usuarios.php'</script>";

    }
    ?>
```